# Java Lambda Expression: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, collections, java-8

I have the following list of jobs, each element is a list containing profit and difficulty:

```
List<List<Integer>> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < difficulty.length; i++) {
    List<Integer> job = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    job.add(profit[i]);
    job.add(difficulty[i]);
    jobs.add(job);
}
```

Now I want to sort the jobs based on their profit (first element of each job) like below:

```
jobs.sort((j1, j2) -> j1.get(0) > j2.get(0));
```

But got the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
```

What did I do wrong and how do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the Javadoc for [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: You should be returning an integer instead of a boolean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is invalid as it returns a `boolean` whereas the expected return type is an `int`.

A simple solution would be:

```
jobs.sort(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.get(0)));
```

or:

```
jobs.sort((j1, j2) -> Integer.compare(j1.get(0), j2.get(0)));
```

Comment: Or in this specific example, jobs.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(...));

Comment: Thank you! And I did some modification and preferred: jobs.sort((j1, j2) -> j1.get(0) - j2.get(0));

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in following line

```
jobs.sort((j1, j2) -> j1.get(0) > j2.get(0));
```

is that you don't follow signature of sort method:

```
default void sort(Comparator<? super E> c)
```

When you implement comparator as lambda, you should pass lambda that returns int, not boolean.

in your case it should be smth like this:

```
jobs.sort((j1, j2) -> compare two lists somehow to return int);
```

or use snippet that @Aominè provided

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this beacuse in my case the problem was with the JDK

I was getting `bad return type` compiling with JDK 1.8.56 so I updated to 1.8.211 and the promblem has gone.